# Not able to unseal data from Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I am trying to experiment the Vault HarshiCorp. 
Version that I am using is `Vault v0.11.0`:

**Starting log as below**

```
         Api Address: https://ldndsr000004893:8200
                 Cgo: disabled
     Cluster Address: https://ldndsr000004893:8201
          Listener 1: tcp (addr: "ldndsr000004893:8200", cluster address: "10.75.40.30:8201", max_request_duration: "1m30s", max_request_size: "33554432", tls: "disabled")
           Log Level: info
               Mlock: supported: true, enabled: false
             Storage: file
             Version: Vault v0.11.0
         Version Sha: 87492f9258e0227f3717e3883c6a8be5716bf56
```

**Server configuration as below:**

```
listener "tcp" {
  address = "ldndsr000004893:8200"
  scheme = "http"
  tls_disable = 1
}
#storage "inmem" {
#}
#storage "zookeeper" {
#  address = "localhost:2182"
#  path    = "vault/"
#}
storage "file" {
  path = "/app/iag/phoenix/vault/data"
}
# Advertise the non-loopback interface
api_addr = "https://ldndsr000004893:8200"
disable_mlock = true
ui=true
```

I have input numbers of key value pairs into vault, and was able to retrieve data normally using Vault command line. But certaintly It stopped working and not able to unseal data from both UI and commandline.

**UI error :**

[image]
Any advice on this issue as I am going to use Vault for storing all credential information.

Comment: do you have vault still running (`vault server`) and initialized (`vault operator init`)?

Comment: I have killed it already. I have fixed it by changing the listenning port to 8201. I even dont understand why but it is just workaround solution for now @SufiyanGhori

Comment: This issue happen again. Have  you got any idea why it happen and how to fix issue. I am quite worrying now as I am planing to put it in production. 
Got this error from vault ui : `Cannot read property 'key' of undefined`
@SufiyanGhori

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with **Vault UI** running on chrome browse.
I have to open a new window with `incognito windows` and it is showing `sign in` window after I keyed in the token Vault got unsealed

[image]